# NoClassDefFoundError in app, classpath is correct (at first sight). Why?

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I run my app.jar as `java -jar app.jar` and see the next error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

**app.jar** structure:

```
    .
    ├── lib
    │   ├── ... (some *.jar files)
    │   ├── libthrift-0.9.3.jar
    │   └── ... (some *.jar files)
    ├── META-INF
    │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │   └── maven
    │       └── groupId-name
    │           └── artifactId-name
    │               ├── pom.properties
    │               └── pom.xml
    └── ... *.class files of app
```

In `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` declared a `classpath` as:

```
Class-Path: lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar lib/...(other *.jar's from lib/ folder)
```

**libthrift-0.9.3.jar** structure:

```
    .
    ├── META-INF
    │   ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   ├── MANIFEST.MF
    │   └── NOTICE.txt
    └── org
        └── apache
            └── ... some packages with files
                ├── transport
                │   ├── ... some files
                │   ├── TTransportException.class
                │   └── ...
                └── ...
```

As are you see, class `org.apache.transport.TTransportException` exists and must be accessible in runtime. But don't. Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: by default in java if you have not used any special tools/frameworks (like spring-boot) you cannot have jars inside jar.

Second: The entries in in your Manifest file (like Class-Path: lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar etc) reference not the jars inside jar but the jars in file system near the jar. I.e the file structure to run your app with `java -jar app.jar` should be:

```
./
 /libs --> all 3-d party jars here
 app.jar
```

If you want to have all in one jar one of the variants is to use so called 'uber-jar' - in that case all the 3-d party classes are extracted from their jars and packaged together with your own classes in one jar.

For example for maven build [Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

While packaging the app.jar, simply put the external/3rd party libraries like libthrift-0.9.3.jar in a folder/directory called "lib" just beside the app.jar. Let you Manifest entries remain the same. While executing, use java -cp . -jar app.jar. Else, like inigo said, simply use a tool like eclipse and pack all libraries inside the jar. Another option is simply to extract all class files from the external jars like thrift and package them into your app.jar. In that case you can run it simply like you want.